# What is the correct place for Partial Views in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Would someone confirm the best place for a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?

My thinkings are if it's a global view that's going to be used in many places then SHARED.

If it's part of a view that's been wrapped up into a partial view to make code reading easier, then it should go into the Views/Controller directory

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: thanks a lot for everyones comments. Its nice to know i was on the right track :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I believe you are correct.  Here is an example of something I do, general navigation partial views in my Shared directory. and then a partial views for a specific Controller in the Views/[ControllerName] Directory.

Comment: I guess there's really not much different than regular views in the case of placing partial views at controller directory...except partial views don't specify a layout file and the '_' prefix? In other words, we can use regular views as partial views?

Answer (score 8):

I think, you're absolutely right!

Views in the "Views/Shared" folder you can access from all controllers and actions. Views in the "Views/[ControllerName]" folder are for controller specific views only (even if there are possibilities to access them from other controllers).